LSTM as regressor in Double Machine Learning
I want to use Double Machine Learning (DML) to do some causality studies. For this I am using the DoubleMLIRM from the doubleml package. The DML uses two ML/DL/NN approaches; one for regression and the other for classification. For classification I am using the ExtraTreesClassifier and I want to develop an LSTM for the regressor. I am a bit confused on how I would do so, as I want to input it as a regressor. Here's the code I have so far with the DML and the classifier. I want to define the LSTM regressor in the code. df is a time series format dataframe which has at least 3 columns for y_col, d_col and x_cols. Note that the d_cols column is binary (this is the treatment variable).
import doubleml as dml
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

data_dml_base = dml.DoubleMLData(df,
                                 y_col=y_col,
                                 d_cols= d_cols,
                                 x_cols=x_cols)

boost1 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_jobs=1,
                      n_estimators=300, max_depth = 2)

boost2 = LSTM(...) # regressor, how would I write this?


np.random.seed(1111)
dml_plr_boost = dml.DoubleMLIRM(data_dml_base,
                               ml_g = boost2,
                               ml_m = boost1,
                               n_folds = 10)
dml_plr_boost.fit(store_predictions=True)
dml_plr_boost.summary

I used to use the XGBRegressor as regressor before, but it didn't work well with my data. This is how the code would have looked like:
boost3 = XGBRegressor(n_jobs=1, objective = 'reg:squarederror',
                     eta=0.3, n_estimators=500, max_depth = 2)

dml_plr_boost_xgb = dml.DoubleMLIRM(data_dml_base,
                               ml_g = boost3,
                               ml_m = boost1,
                               n_folds = 10)

